# Windows Form Control doesn't appear in WPF windows when set AllowTransparency=True

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

Now I have a task to add Windows Form Panel to WPF windows.
I run with default mode and it runs OK, but when I change to AllowTransparency=True, all Windows Form control disappeared.

Here is the code I add a panel to a control, following [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/using-windows-forms-controls-in-wpf/)

Here is the source code:

```
 System.Windows.Forms.Panel myPanel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
 myPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
 myPanel.Visible = true;
 myPanel.Width = 500;
 myPanel.Height = 500;

WindowsFormsHost myHost = new WindowsFormsHost();
myHost.Child = myPanel;
ui_aaa.Children.Clear();
ui_aaa.Children.Add(myHost);
ui_aaa.UpdateDefaultStyle();
```

I need to find the way for displaying the panel in AllowTransparency mode. Thank you

Comment: WPF uses per-pixel alpha transparency.  Which is very incompatible with legacy Windows controls that use 24bpp GDI rendering, such controls become entirely invisible.  One of the standard "airspace" problems in WPF.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It means that it is impossible for loading Winforms control in WPF when the Window in WPF set AllowTransparency=true, isn't it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the different between WPF and windows form when display in AllowTransparency mode, per-pixel in WPF vs 24 bpp GDI in WinForm, we can't display the Windows Form control in AllowTransperency mode in WPF